# RandomPoint in geographic region from Polygon[region_]?

Tags: random, geography

How do you generate a `RandomPoint` in a geographic region?

```
state = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Opacity[0.1], Polygon[state]}]
```

This produces the polygon outline of the state.  I would like to get a random point (location coordinates) in the geographic region. I tried -

```
RandomPoint[Polygon[state]]
```

but this gives the error

```
RandomPoint::creg: The first argument Polygon[Illinois, United States] is expected to be a parameter-free region. >>
```

How do you use `RandomPoint` for geographic regions?

Comment: `GeoPosition[
 RandomPoint[
  EntityValue[state, 
    EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]] /. 
   GeoPosition -> Identity]]`

Comment: @ilian So, it seems that `Polygon` is doing something special with a geographic object. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @ilian I had been puzzled by this as well. Is the usage you suggest reported anywhere in the docs? If not, it would be great if you could convert your comment into an answer and possibly expand upon what is going on here.

Comment: @MarcoB Converted into an answer, though this usage is just a kludge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The polygon of interest is

```
state = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}];
(polygon = state["Polygon"]) // Short

(* Polygon[GeoPosition[{{{36.9821, -89.1329}, <<187>> ,{36.9821, -89.1329}}}]] *)
```

however that expression is not a valid region

```
 RegionQ[polygon]

 (* False *)
```

because the argument of `Polygon[]` is not a list of point coordinates. Nevertheless `RandomPoint` can be used after `GeoPosition` is stripped

```
RandomPoint[polygon /. GeoPosition -> Identity]

(* {39.7605, -89.8648} *)
```

Arguably the region functionality could be extended to support `GeoPosition`s, but as of now this is not implemented.

Comment: Just a side note: this distribution is a bit non-uniform on the Earth surface. It is uniform only in equal-area projections (e.g. Gall–Peters projection).