# Reflect point over a line in 3D

Tags: geometry

I'd like to sample points on a triangle randomly. The following code yields points that are uniformly [distributed on a quadrilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrianglePointPicking.html):

[image: random points in triangle]

```
point = RandomReal[]*(v2-v1) + RandomReal[]*(v3-v1);
```

I'd like to take advantage of the symmetry and transform points chosen outside the triangle to their reflected position inside the triangle. It seems like this should be simple with `ReflectionTransform`, but so far, no dice. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
Module[{vertices = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}, p, r},

 p = (RandomReal[] vertices[[2]] - vertices[[1]]) +
     (RandomReal[] vertices[[3]] - vertices[[1]]);

 r = ReflectionTransform[p];

 Print["p=", p]; Print["r[p]=", r[p]];

 Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Triangle[vertices]}], 
      Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[vertices], Green, 
                  PointSize[0.04], Point[p], Point[r[p]]}], 
      Graphics3D[Text[#, 1.05 #] &/@(vertices~Join~{p, r[p]})]]]
```

[image: what I tried]

Obviously, the reflection above is not specified properly, but I would like to reflect the point, P, in the plane of the triangle to generate two corresponding points mirrored over the edge (`v2 -> v3`).

Comment: An interesting question.  Can you give give us some additional context?  For what do you intend to use this idea?  Do you need to limit it to 3 dimensions?

Comment: "sample points on a triangle randomly" - hmm, you know that `DirichletDistribution[]` is built in, right?

Comment: @Jagra the immediate issue was grabbing a point in an arbitrary triangle to compute [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). I wanted a uniform random sampling and the scheme above looked like the simplest approach.

Comment: A few related sources you might find interesting: [uniform-sampling-of-points-on-a-simplex](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502583/uniform-sampling-of-points-on-a-simplex); [uniformly-distributed-points-over-the-surface-of-the-standard-simplex](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611816/uniformly-distributed-points-over-the-surface-of-the-standard-simplex); and an old question of mine:[generate-regularly-spaced-points-from-the-surface-of-simplexes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/generate-regularly-spaced-points-from-the-surface-of-simplexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other folks have comments on other techniques for doing the sampling, but I wanted to address how you could actually do it with `ReflectionTransformation`—or, more accurately, why you should do it with `RotationTransformation` instead.

`ReflectionTransform[p]` reflects points about the *origin* by default;  it also points the "mirror" in the direction from the origin to `p`.  Given this, applying `ReflectionTransform[p]` to `p` itself will always yield `-p`.  The correct syntax to reflect the point `p` about a plane containing `vertices[[2]]` and `vertices[[3]]` and perpendicular to the plane of the triangle is this:

```
r = ReflectionTransform[Cross[vertices[[2]] - vertices[[3]],
                          Cross[vertices[[2]] - vertices[[1]], vertices[[3]] - vertices[[1]]]], 
                        vertices[[2]]]
```

To decipher this:

- Define $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ as the vectors pointing from `vertices[[1]]` to `vertices[[2]]` and `vertices[[3]]`, respectively.  These are found by subtracting `vertices[[1]]` from `vertices[[2]]` and `vertices[[3]]`.
- The normal vector to the mirror is the first argument of `ReflectionTransform`.  We find this by taking the double cross product $(\vec{A} - \vec{B}) \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})$.  $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$ is always perpendicular to the plane of the triangle;  the plane of the "mirror" will contain both this vector and $(\vec{A} - \vec{B})$, so we take the cross product of the two to obtain the normal to the mirror.
- The second argument of `ReflectionTransform` is any point along the line connecting `vertices[[2]]` and `vertices[[3]]`;  either one of the points themselves will do nicely.

**With all that said:** this is probably *not* the transformation you want, for the simple reason that it doesn't always yield points that lie in the lower left-hand triangle.  It will if the original parallelogram is reflection-symmetric about the diagonal in question;  but that's not the case for most parallelograms.  (Try folding a piece of A4/Letter paper across the diagonal to see what I mean.)  I suspect that instead of reflecting about a plane  containing the diagonal, you would rather rotate about the midpoint of the diagonal:

```
r = RotationTransform[Pi, Cross[vertices[[2]] - vertices[[1]], vertices[[3]] - vertices[[1]]], (vertices[[2]] + vertices[[3]])/2]
```

This creates a rotation of $\pi = 180$° about the axis $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$ (so perpendicular to the plane of the parallelogram) about the midpoint of the side containing `vertices[[2]]` and `vertices[[3]]`.  This will always map points from the "upper" triangle" into the "lower" triangle.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question in the title:

```
lineReflect[p0_?VectorQ, {p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ}] /; MatrixQ[{p0, p1, p2}] :=
            2 p1 - p0 + 2 Projection[p0 - p1, p2 - p1]
```

A demonstration:

```
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[4],
                       Point[{2, 4/3}], Line[{{1, 1}, {3, 2}}], 
                       Point[lineReflect[{2, 4/3}, {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}]]}], 
             Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[4],
                         Point[{2, 4/3, 1/2}], Line[{{1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 2}}], 
                         Point[lineReflect[{2, 4/3, 1/2}, {{1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 2}}]]}]}]
```

[image: reflection about a line]

---

> I'd like to sample points on a triangle randomly.

To answer the *actual* need of the OP, one can use `DirichletDistribution[]` with `RandomVariate[]`, as already noted:

```
With[{v1 = {1, 0, 0}, v2 = {0, -1, 0}, v3 = {0, 0, 1}}, (* triangle poins *)
     BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; (* for reproducibility *)
                 Graphics3D[Point[Append[#, 1 - Total[#]].{v1, v2, v3} & /@ 
                                  RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}],
                                                5000]]]]]
```

[image: random points in a triangle]

If, for some reason, you can't or don't want to use `DirichletDistribution[]`, here's how to do what I call the "fold-over":

```
With[{v1 = {1, 0, 0}, v2 = {0, -1, 0}, v3 = {0, 0, 1}}, 
     Graphics3D[Point[Table[
                With[{pt = RandomReal[1, 2]}, 
                     v1 + If[Total[pt] <= 1, pt, 1 - pt].{v2 - v1, v3 - v1}],
                            {5000}]]]]
```

which should yield a qualitatively similar picture.

Answer (score 4):

This is not quite a direct answer to your question, but if the end result is to have points sampled on a triangle, maybe the following would help:

```
SeedRandom[1]

triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}];

Graphics3D[{
  Red, triangle,
  Green, Ball[RandomPoint[triangle, 10], 0.02]
}]
```

[image: 3D triangle with random points represented as green balls]

A caveat: `RandomPoint` is new to *Mathematica* version 10.2

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip. I hadn't run across `RandomPoint`.

Comment: Related question: [Random point in geographic region from a polygon?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91857/randompoint-in-geographic-region-from-polygonregion)